# Portable electronic musical instrument: energy from pressing keys, no batteries: feasible?

Tags: efficiency, induction, music

on one hand electronic musical instruments are very nice (lot of features: change tonality, change timbre, small number of mechanically breakable parts ), on the other hand they need external power source (electric wire, batteries) so they are not really "long term" portable and one needs to take care about batteries.

Would it be feasible, from engineering point of view, to construct musical instrument which gets energy from key pressing (imagine a keyboard) using EM induction or piezoelectricity? By feasible I mean especially energy, i.e. can key pressing provide enough energy for feeding all needed electronic and speaker to produce sound loud enough? Pure energy balance should be OK (piano does not have batteries and is loud) but (as a stranger to electronis) I do not know what are (energy) efficiencies of different electronic components (circuits, speaker...).

Thanks.

Comment: Just buy a regular piano - the key pressing is sufficient to make quite loud sounds without batteries etc..

Comment: In my opinion: the amount of energy that can be "harversted" from key presses is so small that you would have to press so hard and often that your fingers will soon start to hurt. And even then the amount of energy will be small, maybe enough for headphones but not for a speaker. Also: **why do this**, it is not like an electric piano uses that much energy, (rechargeable) batteries make for a much more usable and practical instrument.

Comment: But it cannot change tonality, it cannot change sound timbe and has quite complicated mechanical structure.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie: well I explained it, I do not want to care about batteries. In my life experience all things which do not need care, or need  less care (good car vs old car, wood burning heating vs electric heating, wooden fence vs stainless steel fence) make one's life more comfortable and less stressing. Purpose of thinks is to serve (a human), to to be taken care by a human.

Comment: just get a [mbira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbira) ... probably the simplest possible finger-operated instrument.

Comment: Can you change tonality or sound timbre with mbira?

Comment: If that's a requirement, then you should make it part of the question. What range of tonalities do you require? Before electronics, ALL musical instruments were human-powered, covering a wide range of tonalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be possible, but the sound would be very weak.

There are already some things that uses key pressure to power themselves, like [this bell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07GKPCWQX) that uses the mechanical push energy.

The design though would have to be very low power, and have a low power speaker that would probably give "little" sound.

You would need deep press key and a mean to transform the kinetic energy, piezo probably wouldn't be enough and you are looking at rotating a motor as generator driven with some gear from the key travel.

Wouldn't be easy but it's an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard electronic instrument, self powered?

I don't think powering from the keypresses will easily work, but there are other possibilities.

I bet you could do something based on a squeezebox! Use a ratchet and gearchain mechanism based on the sort of thing found in those squeeze to power torches and you have plenty of internal volume for a decently efficient speaker. If you can get a toy keyboard with decent battery life off a pair of AA cells, this should be workable.

Downside is that people will think you are an accordion player.

Comment: There's also the [pump organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump_organ) -- more choices of tonality, but a lot less portable. Most people can produce around 50W of mechanical energy with their legs more or less continuously, which is more than enough to make music.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "hand crank dynamo" (google it, lots of hits) to keep your battery powered synthisizer instrument thing charged up.